# Issues looping through .yar files for malware analysis

Tags: bash, yara

I cloned some yara rules from a [repo](https://github.com/Xumeiquer/yara-forensics/) to my `/home/student/Downloads/yara-forensics/file` directory. There are multiple .yar files shown below. I also have a fake malware file called `sample.file` located in `/home/student/Downloads`. I want to loop through each of the .yar files and return only the .yar file(s) that matches `sample.file`.

```
student@desktop:~/Downloads/yara-forensics/file$ ls -l
total 96
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 1138 Dec  8 21:18 apple.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 6494 Dec  8 21:18 audio.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  846 Dec  8 21:18 compressed.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  903 Dec  8 21:18 crypto.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  178 Dec  8 21:18 dex.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  563 Dec  8 21:18 executables.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  596 Dec  8 21:18 gif.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  344 Dec  8 21:18 gps.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 1183 Dec  8 21:18 jpeg.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  580 Dec  8 21:18 mem_dumps.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 1096 Dec  8 21:18 office.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  458 Dec  8 21:18 pdf.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  780 Dec  8 21:18 png.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  315 Dec  8 21:18 skype.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  689 Dec  8 21:18 sqlite.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  474 Dec  8 21:18 telegram.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  332 Dec  8 21:18 vcard.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 8878 Dec  8 21:18 vector.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 3636 Dec  8 21:18 video.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student 1036 Dec  8 21:18 vmware.yar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 student student  491 Dec  8 21:18 win_reg.yar
```

Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find /home/student/Downloads/yara-forensics/file -name '*.yar'); 
do test $(yara -c ${file} /home/student/Downloads/sample.file) -gt 0 && echo $file; 
done 2>/dev/null
```

The problem is that it only returns one result shown below. It should at least return 6 results (`compressed, executables, crypto, office, vector, and vmware`). What's wrong with my script?

```
student@desktop:/dev$ bash yarbash 
/home/student/Downloads/yara-forensics/file/executables.yar
```

Comment: `echo file` should be `echo "$file"`

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. Then you'll see a transcript of all the statements, which should help determine why it's not working.

Comment: BTW, if all the .yar files are in the same directory, you don't need to use `find`. Just use `for file in /home/student/Downloads/yara-forensics/file/*.yar`

Comment: @Barmar I fixed ```$file``` included ```set -x``` at the beginning of script and replaced ```for file in $(find /home/student/Downloads/yara-forensics/file -name '*.yar');``` with ```for file in /home/student/Downloads/yara-forensics/file/*.yar;```. However, now there are no results or anything saying what was wrong when I run the script.

Comment: You don't even see the trace of the execution?

Comment: You can also use `bash -x yarbash` instead of `set -x` in the script.

Comment: Quote your variable: yara -c "$file" .  Usually, you invoke test with [ but in this case it sounds like you want to echo when it fails so just do: `yara -c ${file} /home/student/Downloads/sample.file) -gt 0 || echo "$file".  Anyways, to answer your question, yara probably returns success (0) on all but executables.yar

Answer (score 0):

Your command `yara` is successful for all but `executables.yar`.  If you run it like this you would get more verbose output:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=/home/student/Downloads
for file in $prefix/yara-forensics/file/*.yar
do
   [ -e "$file" ] || break
   echo -n "$file: "
   yara -c "$file" "$prefix/sample.file" &&\
     echo "success" ||\
     echo "failure"
done
```